# Load external swf in a template view -- Django 1.5.2

Tags: django, html, flash, django-views

I'm having problems loading external flash movies from the main flash movie in a template view. So, basically I have a template view called mapView, that open an html file (map.html) where I load my main flash movie `<embed src="{{ STATIC_URL }}map_flash/movie1.swf" quality="high" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="960" height="700">` as you can see I put all my flash movies in the static folder...

the main flash movie is loaded without any problem, the problem is when I try to load another movie (movie2.swf) from the main movie(movie1.swf). In adobe flash I have defined the URL of the other movie (movie2.swf) but Django always puts the "path map" (map/movie2.swf) before the defined URL in ADOBE FLASH, so at the end it won't load the second movie...obviously it will never find the second movie in the path map/movie2.swf because is located in the static files.

Any ideas how to solve this??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found an alternative...but if there's a simple way I would prefer it, because the movies are all in the same folder.

In the URLRequest on ADOBE FLASH I put the entire URL: instead of

```
--URLRequest("movie2.swf")
```

I put this:

`--URLRequest("http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/movie2.swf")` I'm working on my local machine not in a server for the moment.